# Change window size of a plot in MatLab

Tags: matlab, graph, window, size

I have plotted a graph and I need to change the window size of the plot window. Please help.

```
x=0:0.1:3;

for i = 1:4
    y0=[-0.05;-0.1;0.05;0.1];

y=y0(i,1)*exp(-2*x);
plot(x,y)
hold all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your loop, create a figure and set the position as [startX, startY, width, height]

```
x=0:0.1:3;
figure('Position',[100 100 500 500]);
for i = 1:4
    y0=[-0.05;-0.1;0.05;0.1];
    y=y0(i,1)*exp(-2*x);
    plot(x,y)
    hold all
end
```

Alternatively, after your original code, run

```
f = gcf;
f.Position = [100 100 500 500]
```